# Pivot Query SQL Server

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

How can I create a dynamic pivot table, the dynamic parameter is date in a month ( for example month = January, the pivot value date is from 1 until 31)

I only could make a non-dynamic query like this:

```
 SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                CollectorName,
                CountTask,
                dayTask,
                monthTask
            FROM
                #tempHistLoad
        ) DATA
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM(DATA.CountTask)
        FOR
            dayTask
            IN
            (
                [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
            )
        ) PVT
```

how can I  make a dynamic column (date from 1 to end of month) in pivot table?

Comment: Is it possible to pivot the data in your reporting/UI/application layer?

Comment: I would just make it a static list of 31 days. Problem solved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/